# explode digits in batch possible?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch to get an IP adres and remotly start commandline at that IP adress.
The user need to put in a 4 digit server nr. like 4502
Than the batch needs to get ip of that server like -> XXX.X45.X02.XXX

This is what i got this far :

```
@ECHO Off
SET VERSIE= Versie-1.0

:MENU1
TITLE tool - Menu
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO ####################################
ECHO # 1. Command  starten              #
ECHO ####################################
ECHO # 9. Quit                          #
ECHO ####################################
ECHO ##          %versie%          ##

ECHO.

set INPUT=
Set /P INPUT=Make a choise: 

if "%input%" =="1" goto CMD_1
if "%input%" =="9" goto QUIT

:CMD_1
TITLE tool - Command
CLS
set /p fourdigits=Give 4 digits
call :getip %fourdigits%
goto MENU1

:getip
if "%1"=="" :startcommand
echo %1 
shift
goto :getip

:startcommand
psexec -i \\XXX.X%getip1%%getip2%.X%getip3%%getip4%.XXX  -u username -p     password /accepteula cmd
goto MENU1

:QUIT
exit
```

I'm rather new at this language and hope somebody can help me whit this.
(also I hope I'm a little bit understandable whit what i want to do:))
Any help is helpfull also good pointers about what I'm doing wrong :)

thanks in advanced.

Comment: `set /?` has all you need. See the examples with `PATH` (you can instead use any other variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set /?` shows you, how to extract substrings from a variable (the help uses `%PATH%` as example, but it works with every variable)

```
set fourdigits=4502
set firstTwo=%fourdigits:~0,2%
set secondTwo=%fourdigits:~2,2%
set lastTwo=%fourdigits:~-2%

echo psexec -i \\XXX.X%firstTwo%.X%lastTwo%.XXX -u username -p password /accepteula cmd
```

(`secondTwo` and `lastTwo` is redundant; you need only one of them. Just wanted to show you different options.)

Comment: Thanks this is totaly what i needed.
Also thanks for the explanation! :)